# What is the formula to calculate the average value by using sum product with condition?

Tags: google-sheets

In Google-Sheet, suppose I have this table:

```
Name   Number  Price
Item1   10     $400
Item2   10     $100
Item1   500    $50
Item3   5      $200
```

How can I calculate the average price of all item? For example, item1: `(10*$400+500*$50)/510`. I tried `SUMPRODUCT`, but it does not check the condition.

Comment: `SUMIF` does not give me the multiplication to the specific number of item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile thanks to this video https://youtu.be/V-Tsa6NnxNY , I can solve my issue.

The formula is by adding a condition array <del>using `--`</del> as the first argument in the `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($A$2:$A$5=A2;$B$2:$B$5;$C$2:$C$5)/SUMIF($A$2:$A$5;A2;$B$2:$B$5)
```

Edit: Thanks to @JPV for the hint that `--` does not necessary.

Comment: The double unary (--) is  an operation used to coerce TRUE FALSE values to ones and zeros. As such, it is not really needed here. This should work just as well =SUMPRODUCT($A$2:$A$5=A2, $B$2:$B$5,$C$2:$C$5)/SUMPRODUCT($A$2:$A$5=A2,$B$2:$B$5)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data starts in A2 try

```
=ArrayFormula(query({A2:A5, B2:B5*C2:C5, B2:B5}, "Select Col1, sum(Col2)/sum(Col3) group by Col1 label sum(Col2)/sum(Col3)'' ", 0))
```

Comment: Can you share your spreadsheet? Works fine for me. The numbers are not text formatted, right?

Comment: I tried the query function with a simple `"select *`, and it does not work. Afterwards, I found out that Google Sheet wants semicolons instead of comma. After I replace the comma to semicolon. The result is not what I want.
Did you do that in Excel?
Moreover your formula is not what I need. I need the weighted average calculation. In this case item1 shall has 56,86, not 450.

This is my spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G392tn2M33I0t62uVmmLpxaaLiFKwEgHtQ4zzGqi-xw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The use of commas and semi-colons is completely locale depended. There is no way I can tell the locale from your post. If you want the weighted average try the formula I updated in the answer.